# Citadels: Wishing Well card 'every other purple district' clarfication

Tags: citadels

In the Citadels: Dark City expansion the Wishing Well purple district card reads as follows:

> At the end of the game, you score one point for every *other* purple district in your city

The italicization is actually printed on the card.

Does the means "every purple district that is not this card" or "every second purple district"? If you had this and 3 other purple districts at the end of the game, would you have 3 extra points or 2?

I'm leaning toward the first one, because it seems more balanced and the second would suggest a bit more clarification.

---

Feel really stupid but asked anyway. Does anyone think this questions is valuable enough to leave up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was 99% sure that that must mean "every purple district that is not this card", as you suspect.  But how to prove that for sure?  My first thought in such matters is to look at foreign versions of the cards.  Rules text that is ambiguous in English is sometimes much clearer when read in other languages.

I haven't (yet) found a scan of a foreign version of Wishing Well... but this French page, (which contains a comment by Bruno Faidutti the game designer himself, so it must be fairly respectable!) seems to suggest that the text of Fontaine aux Souhaits is along the lines of "autres batiments violets" counting for +1; and I think you'd be hard pressed to translate that as "every second purple building".

(link: http://www.auteursdejeux.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=707)

I'm going to keep looking for card scans I guess, but I'm pretty sure we're en route to the right answer here.  (What language was Citadels first published in, does anyone know?)

Comment: Awesome justification! Citadels does seem to have a lot of rule ambiguities, and being published in English as an afterthought would help explain that. :)

Comment: Earliest Luding cite is the [French version](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/cgi-bin/luding/GameData.py?f=00w^E4W&gameid=9774) (1999)

Comment: I have always played it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have the German Ohne Furcht und Adel version in the tin. The Dark Lands. The rule book gives clarification on a handful of purple cards. It is quite clear. The Wishing Well itself does NOT get an extra point.

Comment: so if you had the wishing well and 3 other purples would you get 2 points or 3?

Answer (score 0):

You have -*this*- purple district card (wishing well) and you have -*other*- purple district cards. Count them up minus the wishing well and that is the number of points.